# SoftLayer API: how to create a ticket and attach files to a ticket

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have some questions about SoftLayer_Ticket:

1. SoftLayer_Ticket::createStandardTicket

   I got confused by the parameters: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket.

   Some parameters(attachmentId, rootPassword...) of this api are optional, but I can not find a way to omit them.
   I thougth I could use "paramName=XXX" to specify the parameters I need, and called like this:
   `client['Ticket'].createStandardTicket(templateObject=templateObject,contents=contents, attachedFiles=attachedFiles)`

   But it failed. If I want to attach some files rather than a server, how should I call this function ?Please give me an example, thanks~
2. SoftLayer_Ticket::addAttachedFile

   I want to attach some files by this API:

   test.txt(a text file) and test.png(a picture)

   And I succeeded to attach test.txt, but failed to attach test.png.

Code:

```
import SoftLayer

from SoftLayer import utils

class Ticket_Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.sl_account = client['Account']
        self.sl_ticket = client['Ticket']
        self.sl_ticket_subject = client['Ticket_Subject']

    def test_attach_files(self, ticket_config):
        if ticket_config.has_key('attachedFiles'):
            for file in ticket_config['attachedFiles']:
                print self.sl_ticket.addAttachedFile(file, id=27333259)

    def test_create_ticket(self, ticket_config):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=API_USERNAME,api_key=API_KEY)

    ticket_mgt = Ticket_Manager(client)
    ticket_contents = 'SoftLayer API(SoftLayer_Ticket) test, thanks!'
    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as file1:
        bytes_stream1 = file1.read()
        file1.close()

    with open('test.png', 'rb') as file2:
        bytes_stream2 = file2.read()
        file2.close()

    ticket_config = {
        'subjectId':1522,
        'title':'SoftLayer API test(no need to reply)',
        'contents':ticket_contents,
        'serverId':0,
        'serverRootPassword':'',
        'accessPort':'',
        'serverType':'virtual',
        'type':'standard',
        'attachedFiles':[
            {
                'filename':'test.txt',
                'data':bytes_stream1
            },
            {
                'filename':'test.png',
                'data':bytes_stream2
            }
        ],
        'attachedAdditionalEmails':[
        ]
    }

    ticket_mgt.test_attach_files(ticket_config)
```

I run this script under linux, and met this exception:

SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Ticket): No valid authentication headers found.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

It is necessary to pass all the parameters, in order that you can avoid any issue, but you can set them empty.

Try this example to attach files, it is working fine:

```
"""
Create Standard Ticket

This script creates a standard support ticket with file attached

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Ticket
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket_File_Attachment

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Define your SoftLayer username and apiKey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

# Build a SoftLayer_Ticket object
templateObject = {
                    "assignedUserId": 123123,
                    "subjectId": 1522,
                    "title": "ticket example"
                   }
# Define contents
contents = 'this the ticket content'

# Define the name of a file that is uploaded to the SoftLayer API.
filename = "TestPicture.jpg"

# Reading file
with open("C:/Users/Ruber Cuellar/Pictures/allow.jpg", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read()
    f.close()

# Build SoftLayer_Container_Utility_File_Attachment object
attachedFiles = [
                  {
                    "filename": filename,
                    "data": byte
                  }
                ]

# Define additional parameters
attachId = 0
rootPassword = ""
controlPanelPassword = ""
accesPort = ""

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Ticket'].createStandardTicket(templateObject, contents, attachId, rootPassword, controlPanelPassword, accesPort, attachedFiles)
    print (result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to create standard ticket. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

**Question 2:**

As I see, you are using this method: [addAttachedAdditionalEmails](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/addAttachedEmails), you need to use: [SoftLayer_Ticket::addAttachedFile](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/addAttachedFile) method if you want to attach a file, it only allow to attach a single file, if you want to attach more than one file in one call, try to use this method: [SoftLayer_Ticket::addUpdate](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/addUpdate)

Also, the exception:

> SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:
>   SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Ticket): No valid authentication headers
>   found.

It's something related with the authentication, if you can provide the code that you are trying, it will be helpful to determine what can be the issue

> Updated

I reviewed and verified that your script works successfully. However, there exists an issue reported about it:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/506

Take a look the solution for it:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/pull/507

Comment: Thanks for your answering! It is useful for me.
I have re-edited my question, and pasted my source code there.
I still get stuck in Question 2.

Comment: ChrisM, please see the answer (updated section) about your Question 2.